# how to log incorrect entries (php .htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging

I have created an .htaccess files that will prevent anyone from accessing a file unless he has a username and a password, how can I log files when anyone tries to access with incorrect information and then ban the Ip address.

I know it in php but .htaccess i am still new to it.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php` to send all those requests to some PHP script.

Take a look at this tutorial for more info: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-htpasswd-basic-auth.html

Edit: if you simply want to ban and nothing else than I would recommend using http://www.fail2ban.org/

Comment: i wanted to ask you after i added ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php
i get an error Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That is the default 401 error: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-status-code-headers-errordocument.html#status-401
Perhaps the path is not correct?

Comment: Problem fix my mistake, the i location of my file was in the wrong place my mistake sorry and thank you