# How can I make .php file log IPs from failed attempts to access .htaccess?

Tags: php

I originally wanted the .htaccess to log the IPs from the failed attempts, but I was told htaccess can't do it. Instead, how can I make the .php that people who enter incorrect user/password combinations are directed to log their IP? What script do I need?

Comment: It's already logged by Apache

Comment: Hm, [actually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659923/how-to-log-incorrect-entries-php-htaccess) ...

Comment: I found that link but it didnt seem to work when i tried it out myself. I guess it wants me to send ALL .htaccess requests to a certain php script that i will find in http://php.net/manual/de/features.http-auth.php?

Comment: No, the 401 redirects only when a login attempt failed. You can make the script for that (log_request.php) that inserts the users ip in the database or in php's errorlog.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to let PHP [handle HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/de/features.http-auth.php).